# why is this key step valid in the derivation of Ito's lemma?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am confused about the validity of a certain step (perhaps the most crucial one) in the derivation of Itô's lemma.

Here's my understanding so far: [Itô's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma) deals with transforming a differential equation of a stochastic variable $X(t)$ into a differential equation for a function $F(X, t)$ of that variable. In particular, suppose the variable $X(t)$ satisfies the differential equation

$$
\frac{dX}{dt}=\mu(t)+\sigma(t)\frac{dW}{dt},
$$

where the function $W(t)$ has the property that, given that $W(\tau) = w$, then for any $\Delta > 0$, the value of $W(\tau + \Delta)$ is a random variable that follows the probability distribution

$$
p(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\Delta}}\exp\left[-\frac{(x-w)^{2}}{2\Delta}\right].
$$

The derivation begins by expanding $F$ to second order in $X$ and first order in $t$:

$$
dF=\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}dX+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^{2}F}{\partial X^{2}}dX^{2}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}dt.
$$

Now in order to obtain Itô's lemma, we evaluate $dX^2 = \sigma^2 dW^2 + \mathcal{O}(dtdW) + \mathcal{O}(dt^2)$. Now here is where I am confused: the next step is to take $dW^2 = dt$. The reason I am confused is that $dW^2$ is a random variable; so we cannot say for certain that it is $dt$. In particular, we have

$$
dW=W(t+dt)-W(t).
$$

Hence, the random variable $dW$, evaluated at time $t$ is normally-distributed with mean 0 and variance $dt$:

$$
p_{dW}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi dt}}\exp\left[-\frac{x^{2}}{2dt}\right].
$$

Now we want the probability distribution of $dW^2$. We have

$$
p_{dW^{2}}(y)=2\left|\frac{d(x^{2})}{dx}\right|^{-1}p_{dW}(x)
$$

where the 2 comes from the fact that there is a positive and negative root. We then have

$$
p_{dW^{2}}(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi ydt}}\exp\left(-\frac{y}{2dt}\right).
$$

This distribution is indeed normalized when integrating from 0 to $\infty$. Now if we compute the first two moments of this distribution, we note that $y = dW^2$ has mean $dt$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{2}dt$. Hence, for infinitesimal $dt$, we are not at all certain that $dW^2 = dt$! I would like to understand why this substitution is legitimate.

Answer (score 2):

I just realized one possible way to resolve it is to map $W(t)$ back to a discrete random walk, where for each time step $dt$, the walker has equal probability of going left or right by $dx$. The mean displacement in a single step is 0, but the squared displacement is $dx^2$ for certain, because there are only two outcomes: $-dx$ and $dx$.

Now extend to the continuum limit, the probability distribution is a Gaussian:

$$
p(x) \propto \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{4Dt} \right),
$$

where $D$ is the continuum limit of the quantity $\frac{dx^2}{2dt}$, as seen in any derivation of the diffusion equation from a discrete random walk. For $W(t)$, we clearly have $D = 1/2$, so we must have $dx^2 = dt$. We concluded earlier in the discrete walk that the squared displacement in a single step is $dx^2$ for certain, so we have $dW^2 = dt$.

Answer (score 2):

Heuristically maybe you can think $(dW_t)^2$ as a random variable with mean $dt$ and variance $2(dt)^2$, since $dt$ is infinitesimal, $(dt)^2$ vanishes, so $(dW_t)^2$ degenerates to $dt$.

That said, the reason that we say $(dW_t)^2=dt$ actually goes quite deep: consider a sequence $\{t_i\}_{i=0}^m$ such that $0=t_0<\dotsb<t_m=t$, and let $\Delta t_k=t_{k}-t_{k-1}$. Suppose $X_t$ is a continuous semi-martingale with local martingale part $M_t$, then for $f\in C^2$ we have the following change-of-variable formula (this is a more general version of Ito's formula): $$df(X_t)=f'(X_t)dX_t+\frac{1}{2}f''(X_t)d\langle M\rangle_t.$$ Here $\langle M\rangle_t$ is the quadratic variation of $M_t$, and it appears basically because for some approriately chosen $\eta$s, we have Taylor expansion $$f(X_t)-f(X_0)=\sum_{k=1}^mf'(X_{t_{k-1}})(X_{t_k}-X_{t_{k-1}})+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^mf''(\eta_k)(X_{t_k}-X_{t_{k-1}})^2,$$ additionally, one can show that $$\sum_{k=1}^mf''(\eta_k)(X_{t_k}-X_{t_{k-1}})^2\to\int_0^t f''(X_{s})\,d\langle M\rangle_s\approx\sum_{k=1}^mf''(X_{t_{k-1}})(\langle M\rangle_{t_k}-\langle M\rangle_{t_{k-1}})$$ as $\Delta t_k\to 0$. In Ito's formula we replace $M_t$ by a Brownian motion $W_t$; thus $(dW_t)^2$ really is just a shorthand for $d\langle W\rangle_t$, and one can show that almost surely $\langle W\rangle_t=t$, hence the notation $(dW_t)^2=dt$.

In addition, it seems that questions similar to this have been asked several times [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/), e.g. you may take a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81865/wiener-process-db2-dt). Also for reference I think Øksendal's *Stochastic Differential Equations* and Karatzas & Shreve's *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus* can be quite helpful.

Comment: The statement in your first sentence is precisely the one I have a hard time swallowing. If the variance of $dW^2$ is $2dt^2$, then the standard deviation is $\sqrt{2}dt$, which is the same order of magnitude as the mean. I don't understand how one goes from $dW^2 = dt \pm \sqrt{2} dt$ ($\pm$ here loosely translating to "with a standard deviation of") to $dW^2 = dt$

Comment: @xdavidliu: That part is in no way rigorous and is there merely to provide a more intuitive interpretation. I am not sure what you mean by the $\pm$ notation, if it's something akin to the 68-95 rule (although $(\Delta W)^2$ isn't even symmetric) then note $dt$ is infinitesimal so standard arithmetic does not apply. Maybe it's more intuitive to introduce rules from [non-standard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis): constant times infinitesimal is infinitesimal, this way $(dW)^2$ "varies" around $dt$ in a region that's infinitesimally wide... so it "becomes" $dt$

Comment: okay, the $\pm$ is not rigorous, I agree. What I mean is, if the mean and standard deviation are both $\mathcal{O}(dt)$, one cannot say that the value is $dt$ for certain, because it has about as much chance of being, say $0.7dt$ or $1.3dt$ as it has of being $dt$. Also, if we take $dt$ to zero in order to argue that the infinitesimally-wide region vanishes (standard deviation, not variance), but keeping the $dt$ from the *mean* nonzero, then aren't we being a little inconsistent?

Comment: my point is, if it were say "a mean of $t$ and a standard deviation of $dt$", then I can totally see this becoming "a mean of $t$ and a standard deviation of zero" in the continuum limit. However, here, it is "a mean of $dt$ and a standard deviation of $\sqrt{2} dt$, so in the continuum limit $dt \rightarrow 0$, we have to either keep this expression as-is, or take both $dt$ to zero, and we obtain "a mean of zero and a standard devation of zero"!

Comment: @xdavidliu: It's inconsistent likely because it's an non-rigorous argument, maybe something can be worked out but I doubt it will worth the trouble. Try stick with the rigorous interpretation instead.